# When instantiating a class in angular, the initialization is missing methods

Tags: angular

I have the following User class:

```
export class User{
    id: number = 0;
    fName: string = "";
    lName: string = "";
    
    constructor(){}
    
    fullName() { return this.fName + ' ' + this.lName; }
    
    email() { return this.fname + "@sof.com"}
}
```

I am trying to create a form so users can input their information. I want a two-way data binding, so I am creating an instance of the User class in the user-form.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { User } from '../user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-form',
  templateUrl: './user-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-form.component.css']
})
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  usrData: User= {} as User;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.usrData = {
      id: 123,
      fName: "user",
      lName: "name"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I finish instantiating, usrData is underlined in red and gives the following error:

> Type '{ id: number; fName: string; lName: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'User': fullName, email    ts(2739)

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because there is a type mismatch. The `User` class you've defined has `fullName` and `email` functions. While when you initialise `usrData` inside `ngOnInit` doesn't have them.

In this case, you can initialize `usrData` object with `constructor` and assign values to its properties like below.

```
usrData: User
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.usrData = new User();
    this.usrData.id = 123;
    this.usrData.fName = "user";
    this.usrData.lName = "name";
}
```